# How to find malicious PHP script that sends emails from my domain?

Tags: php, email, spam

My organization mail has been blocked by a malicious PHP script for several days. I learned that spam messages are sent via the **mail()** function.

How can I find and delete this script on my server? I have tried searching for functions in PHP files through FileZilla and Total Commander, but this is ineffective.

~ Apache, PHP 7.2 (hosted from my service provider)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: The problem its unlikely to be in the server. It's probably a compromised outlook client or webmail account. The details you offer are insufficient. What kind of server, what e-mail service, what context ?

Comment: @Overmind its Apache server with PHP 7.2 (hosting from service provider)

Comment: Did you check the maillogs?

Comment: @Fiximan how can I do this? unfortunately, the address from spam is sent does not appear on the list of email accounts of my organization.(it's like fake account)

Comment: There are files like `mail.log`, `mail.info` etc in `/var/log`. Also `syslog` should show mailing events. The files are quite massive, so search them with `grep KEYWORD <file>` for e.g. a target address to get info quicker.

Comment: The best course of action is to reinstall the server and restore from known good backups. Otherwise you will be likely left with malware, whatever you try to do.

Comment: If your server is not secure and you can send messages without being authenticated reinstalling will not do anything.